# How can I escape the double quotes in "guru" in Zend form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-validate, zend-filter

When I tried to populate data in Zend form "guru", it was returning \"guru\". How can I escape or remove the "" from the text field and populating form data without "" as guru?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have [Magic Quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) **disabled** in your *php.ini* file. They are marked **deprecated** in PHP 5.3 and are marked for **removal** in PHP 6 (possibly 5.4).

Use [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) to find out if it is enabled, and see [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) option to find out how to disable.

```
// Are Magic Quotes enabled?
var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc());
```

If this returns `true`, open your *php.ini* file and make sure this line = `Off`

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Comment: Now I set magic quotes off but it giving me returning me &quot;guru&quot; how I can populate as original like "guru"

Comment: Maybe you're using htmlentities somewhere. Escaping like this is often the desired result, but if it isn't, you can use `html_entity_decode()` to give you "guru". http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `$str = str_replace(chr(132), '"', $str);`.